# Product admin image tab location in magento

Tags: magento

Where is the product admin image tab located in magento? I want to use grid of images.Or give me the path where the tabs (prices,General,images etc) are added to product tab list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your speaking of code (am i right?)

Take a look at the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs`. The tabs are created in the `_prepareLayout()` method.

The image Tab is handled separately with the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content` and is added to the product edit page via the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes::_getAdditionalElementTypes()` function

Comment: Sorry i reach to the page but i dont see where the images tab are added ? Although there are different tabs like (Related Products,up sell etc ) are added.I think the images tab are coming under the attributes data? right

Comment: Yeah sorry, I have edited my post to include the "media gallery" specific case

Comment: thank for response i really got some idea from your code but it not match my requirements.I create new module through module creator and now i add image tab to that , on that tab clicking i want to open the product grid of images where i can upload files.My main concern is how to call specific function or block to load the images grid .This is the tab where i will call the image grid : 
           'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/images', array('_current' => true)),
          'class'     => 'ajax',

Comment: Follow this link : http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin.html I hope I helped you, good luck ;)